# What's the idiomatic way of mapping Doctrine SQL Query Builder (DBAL) to types?

Tags: php, doctrine

I am facing a challenge while working on type-mapping for a query constructed via Doctrine SQL Query Builder (from DBAL, not ORM) using MySQL 8.

The executed query returns the following three columns from the database:

- user_id (bigint column in table)
- start_at (datetime column in table)
- ends_at (datetime column in table)

But by my current implementation like below (simplified for example), no values are mapped to their PHP counterparts.

```
        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();

        $result = $queryBuilder
            ->select([
                'st.user_id',
                'st.starts_at',
                'st.ends_at',
            ])
            ->from('some_table', 'st')
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
```

The result returned by the fetchAll() method gives me back an `array<string, string>`, effectively leaving me with string values for user_id instead of int and string for start_at/ends_at instead of native PHP DateTime(Immutable) objects.

Of course I can do the type mapping/casting myself by iterating over/mapping the result fetched from the database, but I wonder if there is another way to do it in Doctrine (maybe by registering som kind of ResultSetMapping or similar for SQL Query Builder).
If this is indeed possible, what's the idiomatic way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you map the data / columns for the object you are trying to fetch? While using doctrine in symfony projects(and I guess pure PHP projects too and its explained [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/getting-started.html) you are pointing to the entity class in from() method, so for example if your mapped object is `Acme\Model\SomeObject` you need to pass the object namespace and name to the from() method `->from('Acme\Model\SomeObject', 'alias')` then it should automatically populate the object with values (if there are setters or if properties are public)